# Roles of sbt-idea and Idea sbt plugin

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, sbt-idea

If sbt-idea is used to create a sbt based intelliJ project, then what is the purpose of the sbt plugin in IntelliJ? Is it just to create an sbt console inside of IntelliJ or does it do more?

Given this, is it still the correct process to first create a Scala project, and then run 'idea' in the sbt console to make the project sbt based? So is it right to assume that the sbt plugin does not enable idea to create sbt based projects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it just to create an sbt console inside of intelliJ or does it do more?

Just the sbt console.

> So is it right to assume that the sbt plugin does not enable idea to create sbt based projects?

That's correct. See the following page:

- https://github.com/orfjackal/idea-sbt-plugin/wiki

Comment: It also provides a pre-run step, which I used as an alternative the the build in 'Make' from IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. I would add one other nice thing about the console in Idea is that code lines in compilation errors are click able so you can quickly navigate to the error.